# How To add group Everyone for a Folder and give all Permissions to it Via Commandline

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using a bat file to add Everyone group for a folder and give all permissions to it.

The bat file contains:

```
icacls %HOMEDRIVE%\inetpub\wwwroot /t  /grant Everyone:F
```

but it is throwing : `Access denied` error

Why?

How to rectify it or any alternative command to do the Same...?

Comment: Are you running the batch file from "Admin Command Prompt"?

Comment: No, That is the problem if I make it run as administrator it will run properly, So How to run it as administrator using commands.

Comment: To grant access to any other group or user, you need to have rights of granting them the accesses. That's why you have to run it as Admin.

Comment: but how to do it via command itself?